# ParseFacebookUtilsV4 with CocoaPods - "framework not found Parse for architecture x86_64"

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Until earlier today, I was using `ParseFacebookUtilsV4` version `1.7.5.3` on my iOS 7+ project. Then I saw an update to Parse framework, to version `1.8.0`. pod update runs smoothly, but when I try to build the application, it fails with:

```
Apple Match-O Linker Error
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Full log:

```
Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-amxlttymdgjhvifkgqzpcialrpbs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/projectname.target.app/projectname.target normal x86_64
    cd /Users/user/Projetos/projectname.ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-amxlttymdgjhvifkgqzpcialrpbs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/user/Projetos/ProjectName.ios/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries -L/Users/user/Projetos/ProjectName.ios/Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4 -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-amxlttymdgjhvifkgqzpcialrpbs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-amxlttymdgjhvifkgqzpcialrpbs/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Target.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/projectname.target.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lBolts -lFBSDKCoreKit -lFBSDKLoginKit -lFMDB -lGoogleAnalytics -lJBWhatsAppActivity -lMBProgressHUD -lParse -lParseFacebookUtilsV4 -lParseFacebookUtilsV4Lib -lSDWebImage -lSSZipArchive -lSWRevealViewController -lToast -lUIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage -liRate -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework ImageIO -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework CoreLocation -weak_framework Foundation -weak_framework QuartzCore -weak_framework Security -weak_framework Social -weak_framework UIKit -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-amxlttymdgjhvifkgqzpcialrpbs/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Target.build/projectname.target.app.xcent -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework ImageIO -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework Social -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -lz.1.1.3 -lz -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-amxlttymdgjhvifkgqzpcialrpbs/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Target.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/projectname.target_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-amxlttymdgjhvifkgqzpcialrpbs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/projectname.target.app/projectname.target

ld: framework not found Parse for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

link_with 'Target', 'TargetB'

pod 'FMDB/standalone/FTS', '~> 2.5'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.0'
pod 'iRate', '~> 1.10'
pod 'JBWhatsAppActivity', '~> 1.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~> 1.8'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 2.3'
pod 'UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage', '~> 1.2'
pod 'Toast', '~> 2.4'
pod 'SSZipArchive', '~> 0.3.2'
```

Dependencies loaded with `pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~> 1.8'`:

```
"Bolts/Tasks": [">= 1.2.0"],
"Parse": ["~> 1.8.0"],
"FBSDKCoreKit": ["~> 4.0"],
"FBSDKLoginKit": ["~> 4.0"]
```

Anyway, if i force it to use the older version (`pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~> 1.7.5'`), below, the apps build like a charm, no error whatsoever. Dependencies loaded with this podspec:

```
"Bolts/Tasks": [">= 1.2.0"],
"Parse": ["~> 1.7.5.3"],
"FBSDKCoreKit": ["~> 4.0"],
"FBSDKLoginKit": ["~> 4.0"]
```

Is this an issue with the newest version of Parse Framework? Am I missing something?

**EDIT 1:** Currently using `CocoaPods 0.38.2`

**EDIT 2:** They have just released `Parse 1.8.1`, with this message on the Changelog: "Fixed: ParseFacebookUtilsV4 and ParseTwitterUtils when used as static libraries via Cocoapods." I'll test it soon.

**EDIT 3:** `Parse 1.8.1` fixed the issue for me. That's it, everything up-to-date and working properly.

Comment: I have the same problem as you! Definitely an issue with Parse 1.8.0, downgrading to 1.7.5.3 helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemed to be an issue with the `Parse SDK 1.8.0`, fixed on version `1.8.1`.

Changelog (https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads):

> V1.8.1 — AUGUST 19, 2015 New: ParseOSX.framework was renamed to
>   Parse.framework. Feature: PFInstallation now automatically detects and
>   stores current device locale. Improved: Original network errors (if
>   any) are now stored under NSUnderlyingErrorKey in error.userInfo.
>   Fixed: Potential crash in PFQueryCollectionViewController on returning
>   nil supplementary view for footer in sections.
>   **Fixed: ParseFacebookUtilsV4 and ParseTwitterUtils when used as static libraries via Cocoapods.** Fixed: Overwritten localizations
>   when used via CocoaPods and integrating as static library. Fixed:
>   Potential collision of PFObject subclasses instance variables with
>   _state name. Fixed: BOOL properties on PFObject subclasses treated as numbers instead of booleans. Fixed: Potential threading problems when
>   concurrently loading images in PFImageView. Fixed: Potential crash
>   when receiving a push notification with sound set to null.

I updated my project, with `pod update` (`pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~> 1.8'`) and now everything is working properly.